# Php arrays merging and sorting by date descent

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, merge

I need to combine 2 arrays coming from data base (each one ordered by date descent) and echo a new one together by date descent. Studying php sort functions I got to this code:

```
//Function
function dateSort($a,$b){
$dateA = strtotime($a['data']);
$dateB = $b['payment_date'];//already unixtime
return ($dateA-$dateB);
}

// Merge the arrays
$h_pp_ps = array_merge($h_pp,$h_ps);
// Sort the array using the call back function
usort($h_pp_ps, 'dateSort');
//PRINT!!
print_r($h_pp_ps);
```

This will produce results from low date to high.... how to get it from high to low?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing easier:

```
$h_pp_ps = array_reverse($h_pp_ps);
```

Comment: thanks a lot for that one it probably should but somehow it's not working, it just does not make any effect

Comment: I marked the question solved with your suggestion because the error I was having was due to database results and I had to change approuch to the problem, although your was surely the answer for that question thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Subtract $dateA from $dateB such as ($dateB - $dateA) in the return statement of method 'dataSort', it will reverse the sorting order.

Details:

Change this method

```
function dateSort($a,$b){
$dateA = strtotime($a['data']);
$dateB = $b['payment_date'];//already unixtime
return ($dateA-$dateB);
```

}

To:

```
function dateSort($a,$b){
 $dateA = strtotime($a['data']);
 $dateB = $b['payment_date'];//already unixtime
 return ($dateB - $dateA);
```

}